# FATAL EXCEPTION: main NullPointerException in Android

Tags: android

I have two class. One of them is activity. I have a function in activity class and try to call in other  class. In function i can't use view functions(setContentView, findViewById) These functions works well in onCreate. I try to change image position and size.

function definition like:

```
public void changePosition(int x, int y, int z){

}
```

I always got this error. Why these functions works only in onCreate?

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.scan, PID: 26122
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1970)
            at com.example.project.scan.ProjectActivity.changePosition(ProjectActivity.java:255)
            at com.example.project.scan.Model$1.handleMessage(Model.java:145)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ProjectActivity.java:255 :

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.im);
```

Model.java:145:

```
myActivity.changePosition(x,y,z);
```

Comment: Please show whole code which is related, and logcat. Mention which line throws null pointer exception.

Comment: Be specific post sample code

Comment: Like i said, lines show me view functions. In function it give line which i wrote setcontentview or findviewby id.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but generally you should include the exception stacktrace (it wasn't there at first) and any relevant code. With some educated guessing this can be answered but the answer won't be very specific.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've instantiated your `myActivity` with `new`. Never instantiate activities with `new` as they won't be properly initialized for anything you'd use an activity for.

Use an `Intent` to instantiate activities with correct lifecycle initialization, or pass the activity reference (`this` in an activity) to other methods that need to call methods in the activity.

Comment: yes i instantiate like "myActivity = new ProjectActivity();" Should i write intent instead of this line?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Activity reference
use below code:

```
public class YourClass
{
    Activity  activity ;
    public YourClass(Activity _activity)
    {
        activity = _activity ;
    }
}
```

Then use it as :

```
classObject.changePosition(x,y,z);
```

Now you can use method like :

```
activity.findViewById(id)
```

Don't forget to pass the Activity reference as:

```
YourClass classObject = new YourClass(ProjectActivity.this);
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: Thanks for helping. Some other problems occured but this doesn't give error. I can't give positive vote because of my reputation, sorry :(